# Segmentation fault instead of traceback python nginx wsgi

Tags: python, nginx

My setup is nginx proxy + uwsgi server + flask python app.

Without nginx I was getting in console traceback from program and than I was able to debug and fix whats wrong.

With nginx I'm getting Segmentation Fault everytime with error, exception in code. Nothing usefull to debug.

How to setup to get some real code traceback in console?

```
api         | !!! uWSGI process 19 got Segmentation Fault !!!
api         | *** backtrace of 19 ***
api         | /usr/local/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x30) [0x463ef0]
api         | /usr/local/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x21) [0x464291]
api         | /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x350e0) [0x7fd5fb52f0e0]
api         | /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyUnicode_AsUTF8String+0x8) [0x7fd5fbbee878]
api         | /usr/local/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_python_backtrace+0x158) [0x4794c8]
api         | /usr/local/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_exceptions_catch+0x322) [0x446e92]
api         | /usr/local/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_manage_exception+0x1fe) [0x4471fe]
api         | /usr/local/bin/uwsgi(python_call+0x2e) [0x479aae]
api         | /usr/local/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_request_wsgi+0x104) [0x47bba4]
api         | /usr/local/bin/uwsgi(wsgi_req_recv+0xa2) [0x41e4c2]
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like little change in uwsgi.ini helped.

```
catch-exceptions = false
```